# Counting equivalent funtions over GF(2^n)

Tags: combinatorics, finite-fields

Let $F = GF(2^n)$ specified using a particular irreducible polynomial of degree $n$. Now, let $f(x) = x^{-1}$ in $F$, except we define $f(0):=0$. Let $G$ and $H$ be invertible $n \times n$ matrices over $GF(2)$, i.e. $G,H \in GL_n(GF(2))$ and let $h(x) = Hx$ and $g(x) = Gx$ where multiplication is operating on $x$ as a length $n$ vector over $GF(2)$.

I am interested in counting, when allowing all possible combinations of (invertible) matrices $G$ and $H$, the number of pairs $(g,h)$ such that $g \circ f \circ h = f$.

Comment: An interesting question. We get obvious solutions by letting $h$ be a field automorphism (and $g$ its inverse). I'm not sure that there are others, but I don't know right away how to tackle this.

Comment: Well, if $a\in F$ is non-zero, then $g=h:x\mapsto ax$ also works. Compositions also work, so all the mappings of the form $x\mapsto ax^{2^k}$ work as $h$. Still no idea, whether that's all or not :-(

Comment: Dear Jyrki, thank you so much for your reply. Regarding your first comment, I don't see how an automorphism would work. Perhaps you care to elaborate? Regarding your second comment, I see that $g(x)=h(x)=ax$ seems to work. Question is then in how many ways one can express this as matrices. What is the $k$ in the power of the second mapping?

Comment: Martin, as an example of an automorphism of $F$ consider $h(x)=x^2$. It is additive, $h(x+y)=(x+y)^2=x^2+y^2=h(x)+h(y)$, so linear over the prime field $GF(2)$. It clearly commutes with $f$, so if we use the inverse of $h$ as $g$, $g(x)=h^{-1}(x)=x^{2^{n-1}}$, then we have
$$g\circ f\circ h=g\circ h\circ f=f.$$
Because $h$ (and hence also $g$) is linear over $GF(2)$, they can both be represented by an $n\times n$ matrix over $GF(2)$. If you use a normal basis of $F$, then those matrices take a particularly simple form.

Comment: Hi Jyrki, thanks for your clear example. So as I understand it, I will get one $(g,h)$ solution for each automorphism on $GF(2^n)$ which is linear over $GF(2)$. So this is one class of solutions. Do you have any comment on the other class of solutions of your second  comment, where one defines e.g. $h(x) = ax$, and as to when such a mapping can be expressed as multiplication by a $n \times n$ matrix over $GF(2)$?

Comment: All the mappings of the form $h(x)=ax^{2^k}$, $a\in F\setminus\{0\}$, $0\le k<n$ are linear over $GF(2)$, and thus representable by matrix multiplication. That is a total of $n(2^n-1)$ choices for $h$. I am more worried about my inability to prove that this is all :-(

Comment: At least this is a good start, and provides an upper bound. Intuitively, it seems there should be some where $h,g$ are not necessarily automorphisms.

Comment: Hi Jyrki. I worked out a small example for $F = GF(2^2)$. Here, multiplication is defined by $x^2 = x+1$, $x(x+1) = 1$, etc. Now let $a = x \in F$ which written as a binary vector is $a = (1,0)$. For your example, we wish to construct a matrix $H$ s.t. multiplication by $H$ equals the function $h(x) = ax$ over $F$. However, I can not seem to construct such a matrix $H$. Do you agree this is not possible?

Comment: Martin, you need to specify a basis of $GF(4)$ to express the multiplication as a matrix. In order not to use $x$ in two different meanings I let $\alpha$ be a solution of that equation, i.e. $$\alpha^2=\alpha+1.$$ Then ${\cal B}=\{1,\alpha\}$ is a basis of $GF(4)$ over $GF(2)$. Let $h(x)=\alpha x$. Then we calculate the images of the basis elements as linear combinations of the basis elements: $h(1)=\alpha=0\cdot1+1\cdot\alpha$, $h(\alpha)=\alpha^2=1\cdot1+1\cdot$. Therefore the matrix representing $h$ w.r.t. the basis ${\cal B}$ is
$$M_{\cal B}(h)=\pmatrix{0&1\cr1&1\cr}.$$

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12409/discussion-between-martin-lauridsen-and-jyrki-lahtonen)

Comment: Hi Jyrki. I realize now I might not have been clear enough. The expression of $h(x)$ and $g(x)$ must be $h(x) = Hx$ and $g(x) = Gx$, i.e. by matrix multiplication. As such, it does not seem like your $h(x) = \alpha x^{2^k}$ will give more solutions, as they lead to the same $H$ matrix. Right?

Comment: No. Different linear mappings (w.r.t. the same basis) have different matrices.

Comment: Hi Jyrki. Yeah, I think I see it now. The question as of now, as you also said, is then: Are those all of them?

Answer (score 0):

in that case:

I dont have a full answer but some progress is made:

as it is said $G$ is invertible so we have $G^{-1} f(X) = f(H X)$.

now since $f$ is considering the vector of $H X$ as an element of $GF(2^n)$, it is convenient to express 
$H = [\beta_1 \beta_2 ... \beta_n]$ and 
$G^{-1} = [\gamma_1 \gamma_2 ... \gamma_n]$
in which $\beta_i$ and $\gamma_j$ are the elements of field which their vector representations are in columns of $H$ and $G^{-1}$.

now examining the equation we get for nonzero $X$ we have:
$(\sum \gamma_i x^{-1}_i) \times (\sum \beta_j x_j) = 1$

so,
$\sum \beta_i \gamma_j x^{-1}_i x_j = 1$

on the other hand
$X X^{-1} = 1$, so we have,
$\sum x_i \alpha^i \sum x^{-1}_j \alpha^j = 1$ ($\alpha$ is the primitive element),
so we have,
$\sum \alpha^{i+j} x_i x^{-1}_j = 1$ is the only equation satisfied.

so the $\beta_i \gamma_j = \alpha^{i+j}$ works, which is $g(x) = a x$ and $h(x)=a^{-1} x$.

Comment: Hi mnz, thanks for your reply! I did not state this explicitly, but $h,g,f : GF(2^n) \to GF(2^n)$, which is not what you have above. True, $G,H$ are $n\times n$ matrices over $GF(2)$, but the operand of the multiplication is in $GF(2^n)$.